# Subsets of the power set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider the set
$$
\mathcal{A}\equiv\{0,1,...,J\}
$$
with $J\geq 1$.

I'm struggling to compute:

1) the number of subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ containing $0$

2) the number of subsets of $\mathcal{A}$ containing $1$

Could you help?

Comment: >ell, asubset containing $0$, say, can be written=n as$\;\{0\}\cup B$, where $B\subset J'=\{1,\dots, J\}$. Similarly for $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subset of $A$ containing $0$ takes the form $\{0\}\cup B$, where $B\subseteq \{1, \dots, J\}$. The other direction is also true: $\{0\}\cup B$ for $B\subseteq \{1, \dots, J\}$ is always a subset of $A$ containing $0$. Therefore, $T\subseteq A$ contains $0$ if and only if it can be written as $T=\{0\}\cup B$ for $B\subseteq \{1, \dots J\}$. Hence, the question is equivalent to asking how many subsets $B$ of $\{1, \dots, J\}$ exist. $\{1, \dots, J\}$ has $J$ elements, so the answer is $2^J$. The solution for $1$ is similar.

Comment: In your example, $J=2$. My formula states the number of subsets of $A$ containing $0$ is $2^J=2^2=4$, just like you said. Note the formula is $2^J$ and not $2^{J+1}$ like you used. I believe the confusion arises from the fact that $A$ contains $J+1$ elements and not $J$.

Comment: Yes yes, sorry, my mistake, I've accepted your answer.